# Node.js - Passport JWT Auth, returning req.logIn is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, passport-jwt

I use `passport-jwt` strategy here:

```
const JWTstrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const ExtractJWT = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;

module.exports = function (passport) {
  const opts = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromUrlQueryParameter("secret_token"),
    secretOrKey: "nodeauthsecret",
  };
  passport.use(
    new JWTstrategy(opts, function (token, done) {
      try {
        return done(null, token);
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    })
  );
};
```

Login:

```
const signin = (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  pool.query(
    "SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email=$1",
    [email],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      if (result.rows.length > 0) {
        const first = result.rows[0];
        bcrypt.compare(password, first.password, function (err, results) {
          if (results && !err) {
            var token = jwt.sign(
              { id: first.id },
              "nodeauthsecret",
              { expiresIn: 86400 }
            );
            jwt.verify(token, "nodeauthsecret", function (err, data) {
              console.log(err, data);
            });
            res.status(200).json({ success: true, token: "JWT " + token });
          } else {
            res.status(401).send({
              success: false,
              msg: "Authentication failed. Wrong password.",
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.status(401).send("No user found with this email.")
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Route i'm trying to access:

```
router.get('/secret', passport.authenticate('jwt',{session: false}),(req,res,next)=>{
    res.json("Secret Data")
})
```

Passport imported in routes

```
const passport = require('passport')

require('../auth/auth')(passport)
```

When i try to access /secret with the token as the 'secret_token' query parameter,
I get:

```
TypeError: req.logIn is not a function
    at JwtStrategy.strategy.success (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:247:13)
    at verified (/app/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:115:41)
    at JwtStrategy._verify (/app/auth/auth.js:18:16)
    at /app/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:123:34
    at /app/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:223:12
    at getSecret (/app/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/app/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at Function.module.exports [as JwtVerifier] (/app/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/verify_jwt.js:4:16)
    at /app/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:104:25
    at JwtStrategy._secretOrKeyProvider (/app/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:40:13)
```

Any ideas on what i'm missing, or?

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues yesterday, then I dowgraded passport to version `0.4.0`
and, everything worked

Here are my dependencies

```
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-jwt": "^4.0.0"
```